# "Something went wrong" when deploying to Rails production via capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, capistrano

The deployment succeeds, but every page has an error "something went wrong".

There is no error found in NGinx's log file, or the production log. In fact, the production log file isn't even written to after deployment.

I am using Rails 3.2 and the asset pipeline. The only thing I have found that fixes this is by logging into the server, running "rails s -e production", going to the official website www.myapp.com:3000, and then it loads fine. After this the app works perfectly via passenger.

Its as if something is not being setup, that by running webrick on production just to load a single page, fixes it. I have no idea what it could be!

Any help?

Comment: Have such problem with rails 3.2 and PostgreSQL. Did you solve it?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not properly set up your production server. You need to point port 80 to your app (directory etc). Please show us how you configured the passenger? More details would help identify the problem.

Comment: The server is properly configured. This issue only started after I started using Rails3.1+ and the asset pipeline. Basically I need to load a single page with Webrick from where the app is deployed to, then the app loads just fine. Its like the Webrick boot process initializes the correct temporary files for the site to load via passenger?\